# LWC Quick Action - Refresh Page after Submitting for Approval through APEX?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, approval-process

I have an approval flow setup to update fields on the object once it is fired. I created a Quick Action that is an LWC that will validate fields prior to submitting. If the record passes the code will kick off the approval flow. The problem is I cant get the screen to refresh. I tried Refresh Apex but Apex is calling a declarative Approval Process. Any Suggestions on how to refresh the screen?

I thought about using window.location.reload() however the draw back is that it still has the HTML popup window on reload and it seems like a bad user experience.

Do I have to update the status on the object in APEX or is there a better way?

JS

```
    import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
    import SubmitQuoteForApproval from '@salesforce/apex/lwcSubmitQuoteForApproval.SubmitForApproval';
    const FIELDS = ['SBQQ__Quote__c.SBQQ__LineItemCount__c','SBQQ__Quote__c.SBQQ__Status__c'];
    import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
    import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
    import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
    import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from 'lightning/actions';
    import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

    export default class lwcSubmitQuoteForApproval extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement)  {
     
        @api recordId;
        @track quote;
        @track SBQQ__LineItemCount__c;
        @track Special_Lines_Roll_UP__c;
        @track Discount_Explanation__c;
        @track SBQQ__Status__c;
        @track Maximum_Approval_Level_Required__c
        @track ValidationMessage;
      
        @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
        wiredRecord({error, data }) {
            if(data) {
                this.quote = data;
                this.SBQQ__LineItemCount__c = this.quote.fields.SBQQ__LineItemCount__c.value;
                this.SBQQ__Status__c = this.quote.fields.SBQQ__Status__c.value;

                //Must declare that ValidationMessage be nothing. 
                this.ValidationMessage  = '';

                if(this.SBQQ__LineItemCount__c == 0){
                    this.ValidationMessage = this.ValidationMessage +  'Wait a Second! This Particular Quote has no Quote Line items.\n'; 
                }
                
                if(this.SBQQ__Status__c.includes("Pending")){
                    this.ValidationMessage = this.ValidationMessage +  'This record is currently in an approval process. A record can be in only one approval process at a time.\n';              
                }
                if (this.ValidationMessage == ''){

                    this.closeAction();
                    this.showErrorToast("Success 2");  
                    refreshApex(SubmitQuoteForApproval({idQuote: this.recordId}));
                    window.location.reload();
                    this.closeAction();
                    }
                }
     
            }
      
        closeAction(){
           this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
        }
          
          showErrorToast(x) {
            const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Submit Quote For Approval',
                message: x,
                variant: 'Quote has Successfully Submitted',
                mode: 'dismissable'
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(evt);
          } 

          navigateToRecordPage(idQuote) {
            this.showErrorToast("Success 2");  

            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__recordPage',
                attributes: {
                    recordId: idQuote,
                    objectApiName: 'SBQQ__Quote__c',
                    actionName: 'view'
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <pre>{ValidationMessage}</pre>
</div>

{showToast}
```

APEX

```
    public with sharing class lwcSubmitQuoteForApproval {
        
        
        public lwcSubmitQuoteForApproval() {
            system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'Start lwcSubmitQuoteForApproval');
        }
        @AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
        public static void SubmitForApproval(id idQuote){

            system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'Start SubmitForApproval     idQuote     ' + idQuote);
            
          Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
          req.setComments('Test');
          req.setObjectId(idQuote);
          Approval.ProcessResult result;
          try{
              // submit the approval request for processing
              result = Approval.process(req);
          }catch(Exception e){
            system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'e.getMessage()     ' + e.getMessage());
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
            
          }
        }

        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the getRecordNotifyChange adapter instead of refreshApex

Import:

```
import { getRecordNotifyChange } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
```

Implementation:

```
getRecordNotifyChange([{recordId: this.recordId}]);
```

Comment: I tried this it doesnt work... Any other ideas?